# Displaying date in visualforce force page in required format

Tags: visualforce, java, date, formatting, apex-param

I have a date fields which on displaying on VF page displays like 12/10/2012. But i want to display it like December 10, 2012. How can i do it? i am not getting the easy way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the format below

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MMMM dd, yyyy}">
     <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Here is the supporting documentation for formatting dates with output text

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm

And here is some documentation for using the java SimpleDateFormat

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html